# More colors in CMD prompt / Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, colors, console

The Windows's default command prompt only supports [16 colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_palettes#Microsoft_Windows_default_16-color_palette). For some users who need to output colored text art, this amount of colors is definitely not enough.

**Are there any methods to use more colors in a command prompt?**

Edits:

> @DavidPostill  mentioned the Windows 10's 24-bit console. However, I need it to work from Windows 7. He also suggested to install an alternate command prompt, which I will take into consideration.
>
> @Eistein1969 answered, it is possible by editing registry. Unfortunately, registry editing is disabled in one of my systems, and I couldn't find the manual option either.

Comment: Use Windows 10 [24-bit Color in the Windows Console!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/09/22/24-bit-color-in-the-windows-console/)

Comment: @DavidPostill my batch file needs to work from Win7 - Win10..... Therefore this will not work

Comment: Then the answer is no. You will need to use a replacement console that supports more colours.

Comment: Someone posted an answer using a tool called `insertbmp`. Even though it only displays BMP file, it's already ok.. P.S. He/she deleted the answer....

Comment: A BMP file, or any other image file (like .JPG, .PNG, etc.) is precisely _the opposite thing_ of ASCII art! Just my opinion...

Comment: see my answer for a trick that work on windows 7. I have not tested on other windows versions. With this tricks is possible load an image PPM Netpbm using only dos default utils.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to use more than 16 colors in Windows versions previous to Win 10. However, if the purpose is show colored ASCII art, then there is an option.

Each position in the screen is comprised of the combination of a character in foreground color over the background color. Different characters that are formed by different numbers of pixels are perceived as different colors when they are displayed over the same background; this effect depends on both the number and layout of the pixels that form each character. This technique is known as [dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither).

Although the procedure to find the right combination of characters that allows to show the major number of different colors is annoying, the results may be very good. For example:

[image: Mona Lisa]

You may review a detailed explanation of the method used to create previous image at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4125).

Comment: The ColorShow.exe did not work. It says something like "check the application’s version and contact the creator"

Answer (score 2):

Is possible use this trick for display more than 16 colors.

- Use Lucida console font 5
- Disable ClearType
- Enable "Smooth Edges of Screen Fonts"

[image: HSL]

This work for windows 7. Not tested on other windows version. You can view detail at [this post.](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6839&p=46171&hilit=16%20colors%20einstein1969#p46171)

Comment: I don't have `Lucida console` in my cmd.

Comment: I think tha is possibile install other fonts for dos window. In my italian version of windows 7 32bit this is installed by default. Sorry :(

Comment: not sure.... how do I install a font into cmd without messing around the registry

Comment: And... also, there are nothing that looks like `disable cleartype` / `smooth edges of screen fonts` in my cmd

Comment: For install fonts you must use the "reg add" command. I have found this link [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/) The cleartype is a  screen/display property. The smooth edge... is an advanced screen property. I don't know if is possible auomatize the disable operation.

Comment: ok use this [link](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/127337-smooth-edges-screen-fonts-enable-disable.html) for the smooth edge.... I thinks that it possible use _reg add_ for automize the disable/enable option.